# Como validar atributos no Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring

Estou trabalhando com ***Spring Batch***. No meu processamento em lote, meu reader precisa ler um arquivo `.csv`.

Quando faço a leitura do arquivo, tenho uma classe que representa cada linha, e gostaria de saber como faço para validar os dados de entrada. Sei que o *Spring* usa algumas tags como `@NotNull`, `@NotEmpty`, porém não consegui fazer funcionar com ***Spring Batch***, existem vários exemplos de uso destas *tag's*, porém junto com ***Spring MVC***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o Bean Validation segue o exemplo:

Classe com as anotações:

```
public class Cliente {

    @NotNull("O nome é obrigatorio")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    private String nome;

    @NotNull("O sobre nome é obrigatorio")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    private String sobrenome;

    // getters e setters

}
```

Código para validar as anotações:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
cliente.setNome("Ana");
cliente.setSobrenome("S.");

Set<ConstraintViolation<Cliente>> restricoes = validator.validate(cliente);

if(!restricoes.isEmpty()){
    //EDIT
    trow new MyCustomConstraintViolationException(restricoes);
}
```

//EDIT
Classe MyCustomConstraintViolationException:

```
public class MyCustomConstraintViolationException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Set<ConstraintViolation<Cliente>> restricoes

    public MyCustomConstraintViolationException(Set<ConstraintViolation<Cliente>> restricoes) {
        super("");
        this.restricoes = restricoes;
    }

    public Set<ConstraintViolation<Cliente>> getRestricoes(){
        return restricoes;
    }

}
```

Comment: Henrique, fiz conforme você colocou, porém estoura um erro no factory.getValidator();

O erro é o seguinte: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to load 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead

Comment: Você esta utilizando Maven nas dependerias do projeto? Bean Validation  é apenas uma especificação sendo assim precisa de uma implementação como Hibernate Validator.

Comment: Estou usando sim. Pesquisei e adicionei uma dependência a mais.

<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>

Porém agora o problema para funcionar é que o método validator.validate(cliente); não recebe apenas uma classe, está é a assinatura do método:

<T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validate(T object, Class<?>... groups);

Comment: Estou usando Hibernate Validator. Adicionei a dependência citada no comentário acima e parou de dar erro. Agora o problema é este segundo parâmetro que o método validate possui.

Comment: O groups pode ser omitido, segue a documentação do Hibernate Validator  Example 2.9. . https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#d0e565

Comment: Henrique, deu certo, ele aceita apenas um parâmetro, consegui pegar o retorno das restrições. Você sabe se tem alguma outra forma de fazer esta validação. Talvez algo como estourar um erro caso a classe não esteja preenchida da forma que eu quero? Talvez no meu ItemProcessor. Gostaria de algo assim, pois eu gostaria de capturar o erro no listener do Processor para depois tratar a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Você pode criar uma exception para fazer isso, ajustei minha resposta para tal.

Comment: Henrique, muito obrigado pela resposta. implementei ela no meu código e funcionou. Só não vou colocar como sendo a resposta correta para ver se mais alguém sugeri uma outra estratégia. Estava querendo usar algo como @Valid no método para não ter que instanciar Validator.